# pip python-snappy library in venv

Tags: python, virtualenv, snappy

I can't install the python snappy's library in virtual environment. This is the error:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_sebastianbaskovich/python-snappy   
/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', 
open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-sW65K7-record/install-record.txt --single-
version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in 
/tmp/pip_build_sebastianbaskovich/python-snappy
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to install? The library or python-snappy?

Comment: I will trying to install python-snappy!

Answer (score 0):

In order to install python-snappy you first need the snappy library (snappy-c.h ) on your computer for it to compile properly. Install  [Snappy library](http://code.google.com/p/snappy/) first and then try and install python-snappy and you should be good to go.